# Integration over cross product and $\mu(x)$ as counting measure meaning in Lebesgue integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, riemann-integration

I was reading through [this paper](https://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume5/greensmith04a/greensmith04a.pdf), and I encountered notation that is confusing to me. It's on reinforcement learning / Markov decision processes, but I aim to explain my question in a way that won't require this background knowledge.

On Page 6, they give an equation for "an approximation to the gradient of the expected average reward":

$$\nabla_\beta \eta = \sum\limits_{i, j \in \mathcal{S}} \pi_i \nabla p_{ij} J_\beta (j)$$

All that you need to know in terms of background knowledge is that $\mathcal{S}$ is a set of "states", and the gradient is with respect to a parameter $\theta$ which $p_{ij}$ and $J_\beta(j)$ depends on.

They then say "the gradient approximation $\nabla_\beta \eta$ can be considered as the integration over the state transition space,

$$\nabla_\beta \eta = \int_{(i, j) \in \mathcal{S} \times \mathcal{S}} \pi_i \nabla p_{ij} J_\beta (j) \mathfrak{C} (di \times dj)$$

where $\mathfrak{C}$ is a counting measure, that is, for a countable space $\mathcal{C}$, and a set $A \subset \mathcal{C}$, we have $\mathfrak{C} (A) = \mathrm{card}(A)$ when $A$ is finite, and $\mathfrak{C} (A) = \infty$ otherwise. Here $\mathrm{card}(A)$ is the cardinality of the set $A$".

I believe this as a [Lebesgue Integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_integration) (or maybe a [Riemann-Stieltjes Integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integral)?) since it has the form $\int f(x) \mathrm{d} \mu(x)$, where $\mu(x)$ is a measure. Either way, what does it mean to integrate over a space defined by a cross product, with respect to a counting measure function (i.e. the cardinality $\mathfrak{C} (di \times dj)$---and what does this mean?).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am by no means an expert on this particular topic and you should wait for an answer from a more reputable source. That said, looking at this it would seem the sum is just being reinterpreted as a Lebesgue integral w.r.t a counting measure and $\times$ is a Cartesian product.

Comment: Is there supposed to be a $=$ in the expression involving the integral?

Comment: @AaronHendrickson Yes, will correct, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Aaron Hendrickson's comment is correct. The integral is Lebesgue integral with respect to the counting measure over $S \times S$. Specifically, the measure of a finite subset $A \subseteq S \times S$ is defined as the cardinality of $A$.

In terms of the definition, "$\int_{S \times S} f(i,j) \mathfrak{C}(i \times j)$" is *defined* as $\sum_{i,j \in S} f(i,j)$, so the integral is just a different way of writing the original sum. I haven't read the paper, but maybe there is some advantage in writing it as an integral.

Comment: How is $\mathfrak{C}(di \times dj)$ to be interpreted? I'm not too familiar with Lebesgue integrals, so not obvious to me how to interpret.